# GAE creates a lot of new instances. Is it a breakdown?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

GEA creates a lot o new instances and I am not able to stop them. Please help. Could you give me any feedback if this happens only on my environment. In the end it kills my db (too many connections) but the reason is infinitive scaling.

[image]

appengine-web.xml

```
  <instance-class>F4_1G</instance-class>
  <automatic-scaling>
    <min-idle-instances>8</min-idle-instances>
    <max-idle-instances>10</max-idle-instances>
    <min-pending-latency>15s</min-pending-latency>
    <max-pending-latency>15s</max-pending-latency>
  </automatic-scaling>

<threadsafe>false</threadsafe>
```

Comment: It might help others, if you could provide the part of `app.yaml` file that defines which scaling you have configured. See https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#scaling_elements

Answer (score 0):

I have not done anything and today's morning my service magically has started working again. This break down cost my clients to be out of service for two days. So, the solution is to migrate from GAE to something else. It is not reliable enough to use it on production. I strongly do not recommend to use google services. It is not the first time.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem might come from the fact that you are using threadsafe=False, which forces appengine to spawn a new instance for each parallel request. You might need to do some changes to your application in case it is not threadsafe.

For more info refer to the documentation:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/appref

Best,